# what is bi-spectrum of signal

Tags: image-processing, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, signal-detection, signal-power

anyone knows what is bi-spectrum and its usage in signal processing? how can I extract data from bi-spectrum of signal? I want to use bi-spectrum of signals to classify them and I want to knows the concept of it. any one can help me?

Comment: Please provide a reference for bi-spectrum and in which context you have read about it

Answer (score 1):

The bispectrum, is probably most intuitively understood from its definition derived from the convolution theorem,
$$B(f_1,f_2)=F(f_1)F(f_2)F^*(f_1+f_2),$$
where $F(f)$ is the Fourier transform evaluated at frequency $f$. From this, observe that bispectra are simple 2D transforms that allow the observation of relationships between frequency bins of a Fourier transform. From the definition, it is clear that a peak in the bispectrum will only occur if there are peaks at frequencies $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_1+f_2$ without destructive phases. I have most often seen them used in digital signal processing to calculate [bicoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicoherence) for identifying signal components that are quadratically phase coupled, which is an indication that the process that generated the signal contains nonlinearities.

> I want to use bi-spectrum of signals to classify them

You need to be more specific with what your signals are and what data feature you would like to separate them by. Please clarify why you think bispectra is an appropriate tool for you task.